# Debian squeeze: change to hostname makes other packages unhappy?

Tags: debian, hostname, fqdn

I'm working with a fresh Debian Squeeze install from Linode, and it looks like hostname behaves differently (from lenny) in a way that makes certain other packages unhappy. Viz:

```
clements@debian:/tmp/npm$ hostname -A
li228-113.members.linode.com 
clements@debian:/tmp/npm$ hostname -f
hostname: Name or service not known
clements@debian:/tmp/npm$
```

This behavior differs from an older (lenny) installation, where hostname -f does not signal an error. Reading the man page suggests to me that squeeze isn't a big fan of the -f option since machines can have multiple fqdns. That's fine with me, but packages like make-ssl-cert get crabby about it:

```
Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.28) ...
hostname: Name or service not known
make-ssl-cert: Could not get FQDN, using "debian".
make-ssl-cert: You may want to fix your /etc/hosts and/or DNS setup and run
make-ssl-cert: make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
make-ssl-cert: again.
```

I'm hesitant to edit /etc/hosts; this wasn't required on my lenny VPS, and I have the feeling that it shouldn't be required here either.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use FQDNFQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name), then FQDN should be before short name in /etc/hosts. Correct

```
127.0.1.1       ubuntu-1010-server-01.local ubuntu-1010-server-01
```

wrong;

```
127.0.1.1       ubuntu-1010-server-01 ubuntu-1010-server-01.local
```

or run:

```
sudo make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
```

Comment: can you shed some light on the change from lenny to squeeze? Why was this not required in lenny? Specifically, my lenny /etc/hosts has only the localhost line, and everything works fine.

Comment: attach /etc/hosts to question. If you use FQDN, then FQDN should be before short name.

Comment: I still feel like there's many things I don't understand going on here--other packages that provide this functionality--but adding the line you suggest certainly had the desired effect.  Many thanks.

Comment: ran into this - needed to add fqdn, and aws's funky hostname to the hosts to resolve.